# Преобразование List в другой List

Tags: java, алгоритм, list, потоки-данных

Есть две сущности:

```
class GiftCertificate {
    Long id;
    String name;
    List<Tag> tags;
}

class Tag{
    Long id;
    String name;
}
```

Есть список

```
List<GiftCertificate>
```

который содержит,например, такие данные: 
`<1, "One", [1, "Tag1"]>, <2, "Two", null>, <1, "One", [2, "Tag2]>`. (То есть не содержит как таковой set Тэгов, а только один тэг или вовсе не имеет его).

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в итоге было вот это:
`<1, "One", {[1, "Tag1"], [2, "Tag2"]}>, <2, "Two", null>`. Т.е. добавить в set первого объекта Tag из третьеого и при этом удалить 3-ий. Хотелось бы получить хоть какие-то идеи как это сделать.

Comment: Похоже сама логика программы позволяет создать два разных объекта GiftCertificate с одинаковыми id и name. Может быть лучше это исправить? Тогда не придется выискивать в списке List<GiftCertificate>  близнецов   и мержить их списки тагов.

Answer (score 0):

На [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) можно так, если `rawData` это `List<RawGiftCertificate>`, где `RawGiftCertificate` это `data class RawGiftCertificate(val id: Int, val name: String, val tag: Tag)`:

```
val data: List<GiftCertificate> = rawData
      .groupBy { it.id } //Map<Int, List<RawGiftCertificate>>
      .map { GiftCertificate(it.key, it.value.first().name, it.value.map { it.tag }) }
```